# Use a private module from `src/bin`

Tags: rust, package, rust-cargo

I have a crate `foo_core` in Rust and am trying to use a function from there in one of the binaries in `foo_core/src/bin`:

```rust
// foo_core/src/bin/run-foo.rs
use crate::run_foo;

fn main() {
  run_foo();
}
```

```rust
// foo_core/src/lib.rs

fn run_foo() {}
```

Sadly, this does not compile with

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `run_foo` in the crate root
```

Changing to `pub fn run_foo()` and `use foo_core::run_foo` is an unseemly option, because I would still be happy to only be able to use `run_foo` in `run-foo.rs` without exposing it in the library interface. Can I achieve this?

Comment: you can't it's private, other binary is a completely another crate. you are asking a red line with a green pen

Comment: I thought that maybe there is some legitimacy in leaving everything as is, because creating binaries using only the public library interface ensures, to some degree, that the library is usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I achieve this?

No. Other crates, even if they are in the same package, can only use the public API of the library.

However, it is quite common to make items public but hidden:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
pub fn run_foo() {}
```

This way, it is technically public but will not be displayed in documentation. You can also put it in a `mod unstable_internals_please_do_not_use_this` if you want to make it really obvious that it isn't to be used. (Some people might anyway, but you've at least communicated “not my fault if it breaks”.)

You can also make it *conditionally* public using conditional compilation, but that means you would have to `cargo build run-foo --features run_foo_is_public` which is a pain, and library users could still decide to enable that feature for themselves.